# No response from server for url - Selenium WebDriver (C#)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**UPDATE:**

I'm having the same issue after updated to `2.29` its like on and off its very inconsistency that's the frustration part.

**UPDATE END:**

Selenium WebDriver 2.25 version.
Browser: FF (17.0.1 version) & IE (8)

The one most single thing annoying/driving me crazy is about stale elements and I'm still not sure how can my test cases be run passed all the time; some times my test cases passed and some times failed and I'm using CSSSelector to find the element but still on/off my test cases failed....

here is what I'm using to find the element.

here is my code in C#

```
public class WebDriverUtil
{
       public static IWebDriver driver = StartBrowser();
       private static FirefoxProfile _ffp;
       private static IWebDriver _driver;

        private static IWebDriver StartBrowser()
        { 
            switch (Common.BrowserSelected)
            {
                case "ff":
                    _ffp = new FirefoxProfile();
                    _ffp.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver(_ffp);
                    break;
                case "ie":                    
                    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                    options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                    _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    break;
                case "chrome":
                    //_driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
            } 
            return _driver;
        }    

        public static IWebElement WaitForElement(By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
}


public class TestCaseEmployee: WebDriverUtil
{
   public static bool EmployeeCase()
   {
      //....
      WaitForElement(By.LinkText("Select All Employee")).Click(); //<<< see error below
   }
}
```

//error message:

```
Test 'M:TestCases.TestCaseEmployee' failed: No response from server for url http://localhost:7056/hub/session/79b742cf-e1dc-4016-bdbb-c2de93cd8fa4/element
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url http://localhost:7056/hub/session/79b742cf-e1dc-4016-bdbb-c2de93cd8fa4/element
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.PropagateExceptionIfNotIgnored(Exception e)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Comment: Mention in which browser are you getting this error and provide the details.

Comment: Why are you running an old version of Selenium? What version of IE & FF?

Comment: FF (17.0.1 version) & IE (8)

Comment: the latest version is `2.28.0` release on `2012-12-11` should i download and you think it will fix the problem?

Comment: No, it's not, it's `v2.29.1`: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list ....and considering FF 17 *support* didn't appear until `v2.27` I'd say yes, upgrade your version of Selenium at least and retry. This includes **both** the bindings AND the IE Driver, it's had a few improvements since `v2.25`.

Comment: Don't use the main website, the above link I gave you is a direct link to the source code repository - it is kept up to date whereas the website is not. No, the latest .NET version is `2.29.1`.

Comment: thanks i will update my dlls and i'm using .net so the IE driver will for .net too ? here is the link http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_x64_2.28.0.zip

Comment: I'm having the same issue after update to 2.29 its like on and off its very inconsistency that's the frustration part.

Comment: @AbuHamzah If you downgrade Firefox, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve in this way:

a) avoid methods like 'do wity retry' to manipulate IWebElements, because in this way the tests take to many time to run, is unnecessary and tests fails intermittently.

b) downgrade the Firefox version to 5 (maybe from FF 3.6 until 6 works fine, but the new versions of FF throws an intermittent exception like 'No response from hub/session...'

c) if you need to handle elements in your test that is loaded via Ajax on page, be sure to provide a js function that you can stop element load, so you should call this function from WebDdriver before FindElement and do what you want.

Comment: If you can post *exactly* the same answer to two questions then it's a sign that the questions are duplicates. Rather than post a second answer you should flag (or vote) to close as a duplicate.